# How to specify particular directory for git clone when I choose maven project in jenkins?

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins

In Jenkins when you use task with a free configuration you can specify a directory where you will clone git project. But, if you choose Maven project, it is not possible.

How to solve this problem?
Thank you!
[image: jenkins_maven]
[image: jenkins_free_project]

[image: jenkins_maven_special_directory_found]

Comment: Can you give some screenshots? What is possible for frees style project?

Comment: You can indicate a directory where your project is, into your job > project tab > advanced > and check "use custom workspace directory"

Comment: Why do you need to define a different folder and not using the defaults?

Comment: Because I have to use Sonic ESB workspace for building special artifact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's under the Advance menu in the Maven section. 
In the build section you will have a checkbox specifying a custom workspace.

Good luck!

Comment: I would appreciate marking it the right answer if it helped you :)